# Why isn't there integer division in this line of C code in the gcc documentation for limits.h?

Tags: c, gcc

In [limits.h's](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Width-of-Type.html) documentation, it states:

> A common reason that a program needs to know how many bits are in an
> integer type is for using an array of unsigned long int as a bit
> vector. You can access the bit at index n with:
>
> ```
> vector[n / ULONG_WIDTH] & (1UL << (n % ULONG_WIDTH))
> ```

But if `vector` is an unsigned long we'd need `n <= ULONG_WIDTH`, meaning that the division there would always result in 0. Is `vector` supposed to be defined instead as an array of `unsigned long`s or something else?

Comment: What is the problem if the division is resulting in `0`?  It just means that the element index will be `0` , which makes sense for a small `n`

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting "vector is an unsigned long" from. To the question, _"Is vector supposed to be defined instead as an array of unsigned long"_, isn't that what "using an array of unsigned long int as a bit vector" says?

Comment: Oh I see. So if I have an array of unsigned longs, I can bit shift to an arbitrary bit in that array. When n > ULONG_WIDTH the division gives me the array index, and the modulo at the end gives me the bit? That's...really smart :-P

Comment: 'Tis curious that you ask why there isn't integer division in a line of code that seems to have two integer divisions — strictly, a division and a remainder operation, though the compiler will probably optimize that to one operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> vector is an unsigned long we'd need n <= ULONG_WIDTH

Vector is an *array* of unsigned longs.

`n` is not limited by ULONG_WIDTH. `n` is the *bit* position within *all* the bits in *all* elements in the array. If you would lay out all bits in all vector elements one after another, `n` is the *bit* position within all the bits.

```
|----------vector[0]----------->|----------vector[1]----------->|----------vector[2]----------->
abcde......................................................................x....................
^LSB                        MSB^ etc.
```

The bit marked `x` has position n = 2 * 32 + 12 = 76, if i'm counting right. To access it, you have to access 12'th bit of 2'nd element of vector. Note: I am indexing from 0, first bit has position 0, first vector element is element number 0.

`n / ULONG_WIDTH` computes the 2'nd vector element.

`n % ULONG_WIDTH` computes the 12'th bit position inside 2'nd vector element.

`(1UL << (n % ULONG_WIDTH))` is the mask `0b00.....1` with 12'th bit set.

`vector[n / ULONG_WIDTH] & (1UL << (n % ULONG_WIDTH))` returns the 12th bit set if 12th bit is set in vector[2], or returns 0.

Typically in the same fashion:
`vector[n / ULONG_WIDTH] |= (1UL << (n % ULONG_WIDTH))` set's the bit,
`vector[n / ULONG_WIDTH] &= ~(1UL << (n % ULONG_WIDTH))` clears the bit,
`vector[n / ULONG_WIDTH] ^= (1UL << (n % ULONG_WIDTH))` toggles the bit.

Comment: Possibly add this. There _is_ integer division, and that's intended, to get the index of an `unsigned long int` in the array.

Comment: @TimRandall Good point, although I think that's just a lack of clarity on my part. I think a better question title would be "why wouldn't this integer division lead to always accessing the 0th element", and this answer hits that nail on the head